# Obtain the same Maxwell's equation after a change of coordinates

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, vector-fields

In the usual $(x,y,z)$ system of coordinates, if we expand the Maxwell's curls equations for phasors

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = - \mathbf{J}_m - j \omega \mu \mathbf{H}$$
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{H} = \mathbf{J} + j \omega \epsilon \mathbf{E}$$

we obtain equations like the following:

$$\displaystyle \frac{\partial H_y}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial H_z}{\partial y} = J_{x} + j \omega \epsilon E_x\tag{1}$$

Now, let $\mathbf{E}'$, $\mathbf{H}'$, $\mathbf{J}'$, $\mathbf{J}_m'$ be a new field (with its new sources). In particular we have

$$H'_y = H_y$$
$$H'_z = - H_z$$
$$J'_x = - J_x$$
$$E'_x = - E_x$$

The equation (1) for this field becomes

$$\displaystyle \frac{\partial H'_y}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial H'_z}{\partial y} = J'_{x} + j \omega \epsilon E'_x\tag{2}$$

If we define $x' = x$, $y' = y$, $z' = -z$, (2) becomes

$$\displaystyle -\frac{\partial H'_y}{\partial z'} - \frac{\partial H'_z}{\partial y'} = J'_{x} + j \omega \epsilon E'_x$$

that is, substituting the primed quantities with the equivalent unprimed ones,

$$\displaystyle - \frac{\partial H_y}{\partial z'} + \frac{\partial H_z}{\partial y'} = -J_{x} - j \omega \epsilon E_x$$

$$\displaystyle \frac{\partial H_y}{\partial z'} - \frac{\partial H_z}{\partial y'} = J_{x} + j \omega \epsilon E_x\tag{3}$$

The equation (2) can be written in the form (3): so, we have obtained the same equation as (1), but with respect to the primed variables!

**Questions**: can (3) still be considered a *Maxwell's equation* as well as (1)? Why?

My question arises because (3) is weird: it involves components of fields along the unprimed unit vectors ($\mathbf{u}_x$, $\mathbf{u}_y$ and $\mathbf{u}_z$), and derivation with respect to the primed variables ($x'$, $y'$ and $z'$).

In particular, $H_z$ has a different behaviour according to the system of coordinates, because $\mathbf{u}_z = - \mathbf{u}_{z'}$. So, how can this be taken into account while evaluating (3)? This is what I can't understand.

This demonstration is used to derive the fields in the Method of the Images in the Electromagnetic theory (the primed field is the image field).

Comment: Equation (3) is Maxwell's equation for another source. So there is no contradiction that it looks like equation (1) but for primed variables. It probably reflects that fact that two sources can be related by symmetry transformations such as rotations, charge conjugation and reflections.

Comment: Think of it this way: if I'm standing on my head while you are upright, we should measure the same electric & magnetic fields because it is the same source, only our orientation of 'up' is different.

Comment: @vesofilev How can (3) be an equation for another source? It involves $J_x$!

Comment: @KyleKanos I can understand what you are saying, but how to translate this into a mathematical form? I we both measure a field, in both our system of coordinates we can write the Maxwell's equation: despite in the unprimed coordinates the equation is (1), in the primed coordinates can't be (3), because it seems to be a hybrid equation, with unprimed field components and primed variables.

Comment: @BowPark you say in your set up: "Now, let $\mathbf{E}'$, $\mathbf{H}'$, $\mathbf{J}'$, $\mathbf{J}_m'$ be a new field (with its new sources)…”. It is true that it involves current that is quantitatively related to the current of the old sources, but that’s all. You set up the problem this way. If you don’t introduce new sources, then all you could do is change of coordinates, and as long as it remains in the Lorentz group will be a symmetry of the EOM. I think there is some confusion going on ...